# How to replace a HttpCookie in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, httpcookie

The question is quite straightforward:

**How to replace a HttpCookie in MVC3?** *(Assuming we have access to the `HttpContext` instance)*

Comment: What is your attempted solution?

Comment: the cookie holds an AuthenticationTicket, I need to update some data inside the AuthenticationTicket, and then add it to the cookie again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SetCookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.setcookie%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
var cookie = Request.Cookies["cookieName"];
if (cookie != null)
{
    cookie.Value = "new value";
    Response.SetCookie(cookie);
}
```

Comment: I have a question. When calling `Response.Cookies.Remove("CookieName");` The clients browser still holds this cookie? I saw some examples with Expiration=DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)... can you explain the effects of both please?

Comment: I'll do some testings if works, I'll mark it as an answer. Thank you!

Comment: @Christian yes, the server has no control over the client. All `Remove` does is make sure the cookie is not sent back with the request. The only way to make the browser delete the cookie is to expire it.

Comment: I did some tests, and the results are positive :). Hope there are no rocks under the water.. I'll mark it as an answer! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Christian you should be fine with this approach, it is the recommended way.